# What could be the equivalent of a PHP array in ColdFusion?

Tags: php, coldfusion

Working on some tutorials, I have seen PHP arrays are quite different from ColdFusion arrays, and that PHP does not have structures. I need to know what part of the following PHP code is possible in ColdFusion:

```
public $colors = array(
    array(27,78,181), // blue
    array(22,163,35), // green
    array(214,36,7),  // red
);

public $fonts = array(
    'Antykwa'  => array('spacing' => -3, 'minSize' => 27, 'maxSize' => 30, 'font' => 'AntykwaBold.ttf'),
    'Candice'  => array('spacing' =>-1.5,'minSize' => 28, 'maxSize' => 31, 'font' => 'Candice.ttf'),
    'DingDong' => array('spacing' => -2, 'minSize' => 24, 'maxSize' => 30, 'font' => 'Ding-DongDaddyO.ttf'),
    'Duality'  => array('spacing' => -2, 'minSize' => 30, 'maxSize' => 38, 'font' => 'Duality.ttf'),
    'Heineken' => array('spacing' => -2, 'minSize' => 24, 'maxSize' => 34, 'font' => 'Heineken.ttf'),
    'Jura'     => array('spacing' => -2, 'minSize' => 28, 'maxSize' => 32, 'font' => 'Jura.ttf'),
    'StayPuft' => array('spacing' =>-1.5,'minSize' => 28, 'maxSize' => 32, 'font' => 'StayPuft.ttf'),
    'Times'    => array('spacing' => -2, 'minSize' => 28, 'maxSize' => 34, 'font' => 'TimesNewRomanBold.ttf'),
    'VeraSans' => array('spacing' => -1, 'minSize' => 20, 'maxSize' => 28, 'font' => 'VeraSansBold.ttf'),
);
```

Another part of PHP is the `foreach` loop like:

```
foreach($list as key=>$value) {

}
```

I think this could be done as a loop over a structure, but I am not sure.

Comment: The documentation on cfloop tells you how to loop through arrays, queries, lists, and even structures.

Answer (score 5):

The first example is just analogous to a CFML array, eg:

```
colors = [
    [27,78,181], // blue
    [22,163,35], // green
    [214,36,7]  // red
];
```

Whilst it's true that PHP doesn't have something called a "struct", it has an associative array, which is the same thing, for all intents and purposes. And your latter example is one of those. The CFML equiv (abbreviated) would be:

```
fonts = {
    'Antykwa' = {'spacing' = -3, 'minSize' = 27, 'maxSize' = 30, 'font' = 'AntykwaBold.ttf'}
}
```

Note: you don't need to quote the key names in CFML, but ColdFusion will convert them all to upper case if you do not (I don't think Railo does, and there's a setting in CF11 to stop this from happening too). Note that in CF the ordering of the keys in a struct is not preserved; it *can* be in Railo, if using a linked struct (I'll leave it to you to look up about that)

You've a couple of options for looping over arrays and structs in CFML:

```
for (element in array){

}

for (key in struct){
    value = struct[key];
}
```

One can also use iteration functions:

```
array.each(function(index, value, array){
});

struct.each(function(key, value, struct){

});
```

There are also other iteration methods such as `filter()`, `map()` and the like. There are new to Railo 4.2 and COldFusion 11. Previous versions of each had headless functions for `each()`, eg: `arrayEach(array, callback)` and `structEach(struct, callback)`

It's all in the docs.